# MPlayer bug fix 1218510

Tags: mplayer

> **Fails to open due to: PNG read error in /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/main**

People have been able to fix the problem with Paul Andreassen's workaround but I can't do one step.

Here is the work around-

> As #8 Gianni Delchi wrote:
>
> cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default; for FILE in *.png ; do sudo
>   convert $FILE -define png:format=png24 $FILE ; done
>
> I also recommend you change to the blue skins with:
>
> cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins ; sudo rm default ; sudo ln -s Blue
>   default
>
> These also need the first command run on them.

But I am not able to

> do sudo convert $FILE -define png:format=png24 $FILE ; done

Do I have to write in terminal ?

Comment: Anyone with the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Gianni's solution, as described above, worked for me.
Any '.png' file in the 'default' directory needs 'convert' run on it.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default
for FILE in *.png; do sudo convert $FILE -define png:format=png24 $FILE; done
```

Comment: I saw a similar solution elsewhere, but in multiple lines: The problem was a newline before  the `*.png`

Answer (score 1):

I went to the Software Manager in Linux Mint, installed `gnome-mplayer`, and then launched that instead; and, it didn't give me an error.

So, that's what fixed it for me. Also installed and launched `smplayer` without a problem; so, that may be an alternative solution.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so Mint is off-topic here as well.** However, on [unix.se], a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and use the commands below.

Use the lines one by one to avoid confusion

```
cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default
for FILE in *.png; do sudo convert "$FILE" -define png:format=png24 "$FILE"; done
cd /usr/share/mplayer/skins; sudo rm default; sudo ln -s Blue default
```

---

For later readers, you have to install the package `mplayer-skins` first.

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer-skins
```